# DNN module popup window is being displayed at the bottom

Tags: asp.net, dotnetnuke

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zTVrS.png)

can anyone tell me why my module pop-up is being displayed so low, i made the template in DotNetNuke and now when i want to add module the pop-up appears like this sometimes its not even visible.

i have tried changing the css of my template body but nothing happened.

thank you

Answer (score 1):

This issue usually stems from having a custom skin.

The way I fix this issue when I create my skins is to add this bit of css in a file specifically for overwriting DNN quirks:

```
 body.dnnEditState #Form {
    height: 100%;
}
```

When you are in edit mode, which you will be, if you're adding a module - DNN adds a class "dnnEditState" to the body.

This piece of CSS above, will make sure that the "Form" - The main part of DNN, is the height of your viewport.

This then centers the "Add Module" modal to the the screen

Comment: thanks #Andrew it worked, but i found another way to resolve this that is
#html{
 height:100%;
}

giving height to html, can you tell me how this html thing worked what was the actual problem? thanks again :)

Comment: If this answer helped you, please can you mark it positively. I personally prefer to only alter the very specific instance of when this happens, hence the "dnnEditState" class.
You may run into other issues by setting the html height to 100%, depending on what you're styling.